# Имитация счетчика - увеличение числа через заданный промежуток времени

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, счетчики

Есть 3 счетчика, для которых необходимо:
1 -количество рублей увеличивал на 700+рандомное число до 1500, каждые 15 секунд
2 -количество заказов увеличивал на 1 + рандомное число до 3 каждые 15 секунд
3 -количество лендингов увеличивал на +1 при каждом наведении на это число
счетчик лендингов отрабатывают, а остальные почему-то нет - не могу пока разобраться

```js
var intercash, interorder, intebonus;

$(document).ready(function() {


  $(document).scroll(function(e) {
    clearInterval(intercash);
    clearInterval(interorder);
    if (
      $("#b8").offset().top - $(window).height() < $(document).scrollTop() &&
      $(document).scrollTop() < $("#b8").offset().top + $("#b8").height()
    ) {
      intercash = setInterval(
        function() {
          cash = $("#cash").text().replace(/\s/g, '');
          cash = parseInt(cash);
          cash += 700 + Math.round(Math.random() * 1500);
          cash = cash.toString();
          $("#cash").text(cash.substr(0, 2) + " " + cash.substr(2, 3) + " " + cash.substr(5, 3));
        },
        12000
      );


      interorder = setInterval(
        function() {
          order = $("#order").text()
          order = parseInt(order);
          order += 1 + Math.round(Math.random() * 3);
          $("#order").text(order);
        },
        15000
      );
    }
  });

  $("#b8bonus2").hover(
    function() {
      price = $("#b8bonus2 .b8price").text();
      price = parseInt(price);
      price += 1;
      price = price.toString();
      $("#b8bonus2 .b8price").text(price);
    },
    function() {
      clearInterval(intebonus);
    }
  );


});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="b8left">
  <h3>Наши результаты</h3>
  <div id="b8bonus1" class="b8block">
    <span id="cash" class="red b8price">15 512 350</span>
    <p><span class="red">рублей</span> заработано
      <br />нашими клиентами
      <br />благодаря лидам</p>
  </div>

  <div id="b8bonus2" class="b8block">
    <span class="red b8price">103</span>
    <p><span class="red">лейдинга</span> 
      <br />создано
      <br />для 31 ниши</p>
  </div>

  <div id="b8bonus3" class="b8block">
    <span id="order" class="red b8price">2548</span>
    <p><span class="red">заказа</span> 
      <br />получили
      <br />клиенты
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="clr"></div>

  <p id="b8slogan">Пока Вы читаете,
    <br />
    <span class="red">эта цифра увеличилась.</span>
    <br />Лид – это Ваши продажи.</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> $("#b8").offset().top
> ```

Нет такого элемента в разметке.

Comment: да, спасибо - убрал из условия и скролл вместе с ним